# How to create a card with image as background in CSS diagonally sliced

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Card in HTML/CSS, that looks like:

[image]

BUT, what I want exactly is that the background, instead of being just grey like it is, is an image instead.

Here is what I've tried: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cz8mnjhL/)

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" class='image'>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>John Doe</h3>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 50%;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.image {
  width:100%; 
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 42%, 0 23%);
}
```

As you can see it works, but the problem is that there's space in between the image and the 'John Doe'.

I would like to know how to remove the space between the image and the John Doe.

Thanks

Comment: Check out: https://jsfiddle.net/sxbw8afq/ with your clip-path you cut off 58% of the image (100% from left and 42% from bottom) so start by changing that to 100% 100% and 0 23% to 0 70% or something. Then you can work with image `height`,  `object-fit` and negative `margin-top` on h3 to finetune it. Clip-Path only masks the element, but doesn't really modify it, so the other elements (h3 and text) will still behave as if `clip-path` is not there. So to debug you can remove your `clip-path` completely and you'll see why there is a space under the image.

Comment: Hi check this fiddle , i have created a `div` instead of `img` tag <https://jsfiddle.net/ka5hnqf3/>

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution with css transform.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  height: 350px;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #cdcdcd;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.folder {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 120%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">Here is my content.</div>
    <div class="folder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your css:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

You will see that your card's height is influenced. You can the just give your card a height that you desire, like this:

```
.card {
  height: 300px //this is your prefered height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 50%;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
/*   line-height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important; */
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card .container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
}

.card p {
  margin: 14px 0;
}
.card img {
  position:absolute
  }
```

//that's all..

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22050730)

Answer (score 0):

Rely on background and you will have better support and less code:

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding:100px 10px 5px;
  width: 50%;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,#fff 50%) 0 50px/100% 100px,
   linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/100% calc(100% - 150px),
   url(https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg) top/100% auto no-repeat;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <h3>John Doe</h3>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
</div>
```